# What is wrong with fitting a second seasonal term in ARIMA

Tags: regression, arima, autoregressive-models

Let's say you are fitting a seasonal ARIMA model with regressors with some daily data and your best model candidate is: ARIMA(1,0,0)(2,0,0)[7].
By 'best' I mean a model that simultaneously deals with autocorrelations in the residuals and forecasts reasonably.

Now, according to [this](https://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/%7Ernau/Decision411_2007/arimrule.htm) source, this should not be a good model:

> Rule 13: If the autocorrelation at the seasonal period is positive,
> consider adding an SAR term to the model. If the autocorrelation at
> the seasonal period is negative, consider adding an SMA term to the
> model. Do not mix SAR and SMA terms in the same model, and *avoid using
> more than one of either kind*.

Does having a second seasonal AR or MA term really invalidates your model; which assumptions are violated?